# Why did /usr/bin/php did point to a new version after a reboot

Tags: ubuntu, php, package-management, packages

I use ubuntu 20.04 with it's default PHP 7.4

I had to use PHP 7.2 to update the dependencies of an old project, so I used `ppa:ondrej/php`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.2
php7.2 ./composer.phar install
```

I did not install PHP 8 nor change `/usr/bin/php`, so my default version of PHP was still PHP 7.4.

Today, after an auto update of my ubuntu, I restarted, and, on my surpise, I now have PHP 8 installed, and, more surprisingly, it's the default PHP version:

```
update-alternatives --query php
Name: php
Link: /usr/bin/php
Slaves:
 php.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
Status: manual
Best: /usr/bin/php8.0
Value: /usr/bin/php7.4

Alternative: /usr/bin/php7.2
Priority: 72
Slaves:
 php.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/php7.2.1.gz

Alternative: /usr/bin/php7.4
Priority: 74
Slaves:
 php.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/php7.4.1.gz

Alternative: /usr/bin/php8.0
Priority: 80
Slaves:
 php.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/php8.0.1.gz
```

That I now have PHP 8 is a bit surprising, but it's not my main concern wich is:
How come, my default PHP version changed? Did I forgot to lock it using a configuration?

Comment: *"It's the default PHP version"* - ? Isn't the `Value` of `/usr/bin/php` the default PHP version?

Comment: What I mean by "default" is the accessible without specifying a path (since `/usr/bin/php` is in the system path).